# When to release resources in a long running Go program?

Tags: go, resources

I'm building a chat server using [Go and Socket.io](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) hence the server would be running indefinitely. There are multiple resources which I need allocated upon the start of the program such as the database connection, redis connection, etc.

Now I'm wondering when all these connections should be released (closed)? Can I use `defer` in the `main` function? Does that close them when `main` reaches its end? Or should I just leave 'em open since the program will not exit on its own accord?

Comment: This is a bit too broad for a precise answer. If your program only crashes or gets killed, then you could skip closing them. However, you'll need to test your program which will need proper shutdown. `main` should call helpers, and those helpers should have a proper `Close` method that handles most of the shutdown.

Comment: @Marc wouldn't just killing the process take care of that?

Comment: Killing the process does not close things gracefully, it just dies. And tests don't kill the process, they need to shut it down and proceed to other tests.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I tend to do is this:

```
func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func run() error {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

In `run` you can then `defer` as you are used to. However, in a long-running program like a server, IMO it's fine to just exit: The OS will clean up all resources taken up by the process automatically and whatever database or backend you have a connection to, has to be able to handle the process dying unexpectedly *anyway*. This is called "crash-only software".

For tests, you should build your code in a way that it doesn't depend on global state - e.g. have a struct that has fields for the database connections etc. Make the business logic a method on that struct (or a function taking it). You can then in your `main` populate such a struct and call its methods. And for testing, you can populate a struct, call its methods for whatever tests you want to do and then tear down the connections at the end of your test.